# Does Einstein's derivation of the Lorentz transformation have a mathematical error?

Tags: special-relativity

The article ["Mathematical Inconsistencies in
Einstein's Derivation of the Lorentz Transformation"](http://www.physicsmyths.org.uk/lorentz.htm) says that Einstein's derivation of the Lorentz transformation has some mathematical error, and his opinion seems to be true. Is Einstein really wrong?  (I'm not asking about whether the Lorentz transformation is wrong.)

Comment: could you be more precise ?

Comment: Please include the error you are asking about into the post - relying on external links carries the danger that the question becomes non-sensical if the link stops working.

Comment: That site about physics myths from the UK is full of wrong, unclear, and/or confused statements about the interpretation and validity of much of physics. It seems to be from one person. He's got a long list of those statements and claims,from Relativity to Schroedinger's equation to Maxwell's equations to Hooke's law, etc. not a good reference to waste time on on this site, completely out of the mainstream and understood physics. If I could vote I'd vote to delete this question. Answering these questions encourages a downgrade of the quality of the site with more of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the equation number on the linked page:

A)  Einstein goes from 1) and 2) to 3) and 4).  This assumes linearity.

B)  Einstein goes from "3) holds for positive $x$" to "3 holds for all $x$".  This follows from linearity.

Einstein either has or has not previously established linearity.  If not, then there is a gap in the argument occurring before A).  If so, then there is no gap.

The author claims that there is a gap occurring between A) and B).  In neither case is this correct.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know the precise way followed by Einstein, but interpreting what the weird site tries to quote, I think Einstein's idea is correct. Assume that *the transformation of coordinates $$\mathbb R^2 \ni (x,t) \to (x',t')\in \mathbb R^2$$ is linear*. If physics says that $$\mbox{$x\pm ct=0\quad $ if and only if $\quad x'\pm ct'=0$,}\tag{0}$$ then the form of the linear transformation between the two coordinate frames must necessarily satisfy $$x+ct = a(x'+ct')\tag{1}$$ $$x-ct = b(x'-ct')\tag{2}$$ for some constants $a,b$.

**PROOF**. Pass to light coordinates $u = x+ct$, $v = x-ct$ and  $u' = x'+ct'$, $v' = x'-ct'$. The transformation of coordinates remains linear and the physical constraint (0) is now $$\mbox{$u=0\quad $ if and only if $\quad u'=0$}$$ $$\mbox{$v=0\quad $ if and only if $\quad v'=0$.}$$ The only possible linear relation between coordinates $(u,v)$ and coordinates $(u',v')$ is given by a *diagonal matrix*, which is exactly what (1) and (2) say.